# AirFlow - No module named 'pyodbc'

Tags: python, airflow

I'm learning AirFlow and when running the following import codes on my py. file i'm having the **"Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/file.py] No module named 'pyodbc'"** error on my Airflow webserver.

I dont know what is happening since i have pyodbc installed on my python.

Here are my imports:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator
form datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import sqlachemy
import zipfile
```

And log of my DAG running with error:

```
    [2021-03-16 15:28:14,316] {{taskinstance.py:887}} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): escreve_dw> on 2021-03-16T15:27:03.248408+00:00
[2021-03-16 15:28:14,321] {{standard_task_runner.py:53}} INFO - Started process 84 to run task
[2021-03-16 15:28:14,491] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: treino-05.escreve_dw 2021-03-16T15:27:03.248408+00:00 [running]> 8ab4027ba82f
[2021-03-16 15:28:15,437] {{taskinstance.py:1128}} ERROR - No module named 'pyodbc'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 966, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/treino05.py", line 168, in escreve_dw
    "mssql+pyodbc://SA:FLorestas#12@127.0.0.1/ENADE?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 479, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 87, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/connectors/pyodbc.py", line 37, in dbapi
    return __import__("pyodbc")
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'
[2021-03-16 15:28:15,475] {{taskinstance.py:1185}} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.dag_id=treino-05, task_id=escreve_dw, execution_date=20210316T152703, start_date=20210316T152814, end_date=20210316T152815
[2021-03-16 15:28:24,204] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2021-03-16 15:28:24,204] {{local_task_job.py:103}} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

If i just delete the "import pyodbc" line the DAG run's perfectly but i'm trying to send the results to my SQL Server.

Comment: Please put the error and imports as text instead of images.

Comment: What executor are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.8.5 with Celery Executor from docker-airflow. Here is my function calling the engine to create my connection:

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
              "mssql+pyodbc://SA:Testing@127.0.0.1/ENADE?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server")

Comment: You might be running multiple Python environments .. Check the system path for your python in a shell and check if pyodbc is installed in the `/site-packages` for the Python distribution running your Airflow. Are you installing the package during your image build?

Comment: It's possible that the library is installed on the machine that runs the scheduler but not on the workers. Can you run pip freeze on the workers to verify if the library is installed on all workers?